# Write descriptor failed - HM-10 BLE

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, hm-10

I have problem with HM-10 BLE module with V705 firmware. When I try to connect to the module with Bluetooth Serial Monitor app(Xiaomi Redmi 5 Plus, MIUI 11.0.2 Global, Android 8.1), I get `write descriptor failed` error. UUID is 0xFFE0(default). Same module works fine with V609 firmware.
Also, phone gets paired with mthe module if I use BLE Scanner app - [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIJMe.png) on info BLE Scanner sees.

I turned on Bluetooth debbuging in Dev. options and I found this.

[image: Package 306]

I'm new to Bluetooth (LE). Also, if I try to pair with the module from phone's settings, if module doesn't require PIN, then phone can't pair, but if it requires PIN, then phone can pair. Why? 
Why with V705 firmware pairing doesn't work but with V609 works without any problems? All settings are untouched.
HM-10 will be used for DIY project. App for the project will be done soon, so for now I use Bluetooth Serial Monitor app to see packages from BT. Thanks for help!

Comment: I faced the same issue, I reverted back to v609. Is there any special reason why we should upgrade to 705?

Comment: No, for me. Everything I need, V609 has. Only reason to upgrade firmware is to stay up-to-date 

Answer (score 1):

I found this could be resolved by setting the HM module bond mode to "auth and bonded" using AT+TYPE3.
Pairing before connecting in the app is most effective; when I left the BT module unpaired and attempted a connection in the app, there were multiple prompts and the app said the connection failed. The device had been paired, however, and trying the connection again worked fine.

BTW: "the app" = Bluetooth Serial Terminal, so not the same as the OP referred to, but the symptom appears to be the same. I hope someone can confirm "works for me" in the OP's app!